# ImportError: No module named twitter

Tags: python, installation, twitter, module, pip

I keep getting the following error when trying to run a python file:

```
    import twitter
ImportError: No module named twitter
```

I've tried:

```
pip install twitter
```

I've tried:

```
pip uninstall twitter
pip install twitter
```

I've tried adding the directories to the PATH... (Right-click 'This PC' -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> Edit Path for both User and System Variables... I made New environment variables as follows in both User and System:

- C:\Users[...]\Programs\Python\Python39
- C:\Users[...]\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts
- c:\users[...]\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)

I've also tried Settings -> Manage app execution aliases -> turning off python.exe and python3.exe (this was suggested elsewhere).

Any idea where I might be going wrong? Any advice appreciated...

Comment: try `pip3 install twitter` and run `pip3 freeze` to check its really installed

Comment: Run pip as a python module, i.e. `py -m pip`. This is suggested in the [docs](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#ensure-you-can-run-pip-from-the-command-line) and helps avoid the case in which packages are installed to the wrong sites-packages location.